# Why does JBehave test run within Android Studio unit test folder, but fail within integration test folder?

Tags: android-studio, android-testing, jbehave

I'm new to JBehave and trying to get a simple test running within Android Studio. I've started with a new project (specifying "Add no activity"), modified the app/build.gradle file to include the dependency for JBehave, and added 3 files: app/stories/example.story, IntegrationTestStoryRunner.java and ExampleSteps.java. I can successfully run IntegrationTestStoryRunner when the 2 java files are located in the src/test/java/... folder, but when I move the identical files to the src/androidTest/java/... folder the build fails.

I'm using:

```
Android Studio v3.1.4 (latest updates as of 9/23/2018)
JBehave Syntax Support plugin v1.62
Running on Windows 10
```

Here is the example.story file (default created by plugin):

```
Narrative:
As a user
I want to perform an action
So that I can achieve a business goal

Scenario: scenario description
Given a system state
When I do something
Then system is in a different state
```

Here is the JBehave Embedder file, IntegrationTestStoryRunner.java (from *Test-Driven Java Development - Garcia/Farcic*):

```java
package com.pepperhawk.example.jbehave;

import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.io.*;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.FilePrintStreamFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
import org.jbehave.core.reporters.StoryReporterBuilder;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class IntegrationTestStoryRunner extends JUnitStories {

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(getReporter())
                .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromURL());
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> storyPaths() {
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(
                CodeLocations.codeLocationFromPath("").getFile(),
                Collections.singletonList("stories/**/*.story"),
                new ArrayList<String>(),
                "file:"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new ExampleSteps());
    }

    private StoryReporterBuilder getReporter() {
        return new StoryReporterBuilder()
                .withPathResolver(new FilePrintStreamFactory.ResolveToSimpleName())
                .withDefaultFormats()
                .withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.HTML);
    }
}
```

Here is the ExampleSteps.java file:

```java
package com.pepperhawk.example.jbehave;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.*;

public class ExampleSteps {

    @Given("a system state")
    public void givenSystemState() {
    }

    @When("I do something")
    public void whenIDoSomething() {
    }

    @Then("system is in a different state")
    public void thenSystemInDifferentState() {
    }
}
```

And lastly my app/gradle.build file. Only the jbehave line was added at the end:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pepperhawk.example.jbehave"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation "org.jbehave:jbehave-core:4.3.5"
}
```

I receive two build errors. Here's the shortest:

```
Program type already present: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

I've truncated the larger error (let me know if you need more):

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\69.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\71.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\72.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\73.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\74.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\77.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\81.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\82.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\83.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\84.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\86.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\87.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\88.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\89.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\90.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\91.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\92.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\93.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\94.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\95.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\96.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\97.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\98.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\99.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\100.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\101.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\102.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\103.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\104.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\105.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\106.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\107.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\108.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\109.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\112.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\114.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\117.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\118.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\Lenny\Projects\SupportProjectsEtc\JBehave\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\androidTest\debug\14.jar, 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this for your StoryPaths:

```java
@Override
protected List<String> storyPaths() {

    URL searchLoc = CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass());

    return new StoryFinder().findPaths(searchLoc, Arrays.asList("**/CalcTest.story",
                                                                "**/ScrollTest.story",
                                                                ""),
                                                  Arrays.asList("**/excluded*.story"));

}
```

I haven't looked any further than that in your code, so there might be other issues, but I'm guessing that this is your problem.  Obviously, you can replace the array list with whatever files you want to include, this is just one from my Appium project.

I have my info stored in a standard maven file structure with the testrunner itself in src/test/java/(package folders)/testrunners and the stories in src/test/resources/(package folders)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for your response. But I don't understand how this relates to the failures I'm seeing. When I use your suggestions and run with the debugger, `searchLoc` contains `file:/<my_project>/app/build/intermediates/classes/test/debug/`. My stories do not reside within this sub-structure. Using this I get the same two errors for my integration test runner, and when I run it in the unit test folder it completes w/o error (as before), but now cannot find the `example.story` file. How does this relate to either the "Program type already present" or RuntimeException errors I'm seeing?

Comment: I take it that it's not finding the story files, and I think it's because your version does not specify the proper class location, I see `CodeLocations.codeLocationFromPath("").getFile(),` which might work with your original directory structure, but since you're moving the stories to another folder, it cannot locate the stories.  Your version further specifies to look for any story files under and folder under /stories.  Like I said, I wasn't sure this was your answer, but it jumped out at me.  What does your `codeLocationFromPath("")` return?

Comment: My stories exist in the `<my_project>/app/stories` folder. The unit test runner compiles, runs, and finds it correctly. The integration test runner (identical code) will not compile (the problem I'm trying to solve). Running unit test runner `codeLocationFromPath("").getFile()` returns `<my_project>/app/` as expected.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to help.  I run my projects under maven, perhaps there is a difference there as opposed to gradle.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is an Android Studio / Gradle configuration issue. Thx for trying.